# How to add attribute to node programmatically with saxon s9api?

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I'm trying to generate multiple static html pages having an xml file and an xsl transformation. I used an iterator to do a transformation for every html page.

I'd like to modify a Node and add an attribute. I saw some examples and wrote the code below but I don't know how to retrieve NamePool,  the s9api has to be changed because the "getNamePool()" is not listed in NodeInfo or MutableNodeInfo.

How can I add an attribute to node properly and how can I retrieve NamePool?

```
Processor processor = new Processor(false);
XsltCompiler compiler = processor.newXsltCompiler();
XsltTransformer transformer = compiler.compile(new StreamSource(new File(xlsFilePath))).load();
XdmNode source = processor.newDocumentBuilder().build(new StreamSource(new File(xmlFilePath)));
XdmValue xdmValue = processor.newXPathCompiler().evaluate(xpathExpression, source);
     for (XdmItem xdmItem : xdmValue) {
         XdmNode xdmNode = (XdmNode)xdmItem;

         MutableNodeInfo node = (MutableNodeInfo)xdmNode.getUnderlyingNode();
         NodeInfo nodeInfo = (NodeInfo)xdmNode.getUnderlyingNode().;
         NamePool namePool = ...//retrieve namePoll
         CodedName codedName = new CodedName(node.getFingerprint(), node.getPrefix(), namePool);
         node.addAttribute(codedName, BuiltInAtomicType.UNTYPED_ATOMIC, "1", 0);

         Serializer out = processor.newSerializer(new File(outputFolderPath + xdmNode.getAttributeValue(new QName("id")) +".html"));
         out.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.METHOD, "html");
         out.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.INDENT, "yes");
         out.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.VERSION, "5");
         transformer.setInitialContextNode(xdmNode);
         transformer.setDestination(out);
         transformer.transform();
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

The update interfaces in MutableNodeInfo are designed for use by the XQuery Update feature: there's nothing technically preventing them being used directly from a Java application, but they weren't designed for usability, and they haven't been tested independently of XQuery Update, so if used in unintended or unsupported ways, they may crash.

You can get access to the NamePool as Processor.getUnderlyingConfiguration().getNamePool().

I think you would probably find it more convenient to use FingerprintedQName as the NodeName implementation, then you don't need to worry about fingerprints and the NamePool.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I tried  FingerprintedQName but on building time I got: net.sf.saxon.tree.tiny.TinyElementImpl cannot be cast to net.sf.saxon.om.MutableNodeInfo. What is missing to get properly add of a attribute?